# Treatment of Chandalas

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, caste-system

Within Ithihasas there seems to be bad treatment of Chandalas as Bhishma recounts. By Chandala I mean a child born to a Brahmin mother & Shudra father. Are there any alternative treatments specifically for mixed Varnas?

Comment: There are only 4 varnas according to the Vedas. There can be no mixed varnas without violating the Vedas.

Comment: There is no such thing like *Mixed Verna*.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7458.html

Comment: @Haridasa Where you found that *Chandala* word? Read this: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7458.html#:~:text=misery)%20cannot%20exist%3F%22-,%22The%20serpent%20said%2C,conduct%2C%20him%20have%20I%2C%20ere%20now%2C%20designated%20as%20a%20Brahmana.%27,-The%20serpent%20replied Once purified, promicious verna is regarded as Brahmana.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I know it talks about mixed varna purification rites and a Brahmana by qualities, but I still don't understand how Chandalas were treated by the Anusasanika Parva by Bhishma says how they do jobs such as executioners and are allowed the possessions of criminals. So, I wanted to see if there are other ways in which Chandalas are seen or have been treated. I know Ramayana glorifies the leader of the Chandalas for helping him.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha O prince; of serpents, Swayambhuba Manu has declared, that the mixed castes are to be regarded as better than the (other) classes, if having gone through the ceremonies of purification, the latter do not conform to the rules of good conduct, O excellent snake! Whosoever now conforms to the rules of pure and virtuous conduct, him have I, ere now, designated as a Brahmana.' Mixed caste is in the verses you mentioned lol.

Comment: @Haridasa *Chandala* (which is a slur in modern times), literally used to refer to **casteless persons**. You cannot be a *casteless* person by birth, nor even by birth (if it were by birth then your caste much match the father's and mother's gunas too).

Comment: *Mixed Caste* **is different** from *Chandala*, that's why I'm asking you where you got the word *Chandala* here. Mixed Caste implies inter-Verna marriage, which is pretty much discussed, *Chandala* means the one who doesn't belongs to any group, totally jobless or unemployed or mad.

Comment: Concept of mixed castes like pratiloma-chandala exists in vedas like jaimineya brahmana, taittirya, katyayana srauta sutra, etc. and is exactly same as what is there in manusmriti. So castleless translation is wrong as the word for castleless would be mleccha

Comment: @ekAntika true, but are their mentions of chandalas doing other works as well or ability to preform such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bhishma is only referring to birth of a man as a chandala based on previous birth karma as per **chandogya upanishad 5.10.7** :

> *7. 'Those whose conduct has been good, will quickly attain some good birth, the birth of a Brahmana, or a Kshatriya, or a Vaisya. **But those**
> **whose conduct has been evil, will quickly attain an evil birth**, the
> birth of a dog, or a hog, or a **chandala**.*

Alternative treatments of chandala :

> ***padma purana-svargakhanda-ch50:***
>
> *17b-39. Viṣṇu, the lord, himself liberates a fool or a cāṇḍāla to whom Viṣṇu is dear.*
>
> ***padmapurana-uttarakhanda-ch132 :***
>
> *2-23. A cāṇḍāla having devotion is worshipped even by gods.*

Profession :

manusmriti ch. X :

> *55. By day they may go about for the purpose of their work, distinguished by marks at the king's command, and they shall carry out
> the corpses (of persons) who have no relatives; that is a settled
> rule.*
>
> *56. By the king's order they shall always execute the criminals, in accordance with the law, and they shall take for themselves the
> clothes, the beds, and the ornaments of (such) criminals.*

Comment: I mean in more social terms

Comment: added details of profession

Comment: So are they restricted to those types of work, and those verses specify a religious Chandala I mean regular ones more or less.

Comment: I may not have been specific, but I want to know if they're allowed to do other work or if they're restricted to such tasks essentially. :>

Comment: Here's the correct translation of Ch Upn 5.10.7: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc239196.html#:~:text=7.%20Among%20them,a%20casteless%20person.